# Extracting/Scraping text from a href inside p inside div

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, screen-scraping

I am using beautiful soup(bs4) and Python I currently have this structure

```
<div class="class1">
  <a class="name" href="/doctor/dr-xxxxxxxxx"><h2>Dr. XX XXXX</h2></a>
  <p class="specialties"><a href="/location/abcd">ab cd</a></p>
  <p class="doc-clinic-name">
     <a class="light_grey link" href="/clinic/fff">f ff</a>
  </p>
</div>


<div class="class2">
  <p class="locality">
    <a class="link grey" href="/location/doctors/ccc">c cc</a>
  </p>
  <p class="fees">INR 999</p>
  <div class="timings">
       <p><span class="strong">MON-SAT</span><br/><span>11:00AM-1:00PM</span>                                   <span>6:00PM-8:00PM</span></p>
  <div class="clear"></div>
</div>
```

So far the code i have is this

```
import urllib2
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

soup = BeautifulSoup(urllib2.urlopen('abc.com').read())

 for post in soup.find("div", "class1"):
print post

for x in soup.find("div", "class2"):
    print x
```

So basically post and x contain the divs class1 and class2. Now the information I want to extract is

DR.XXXXXX
abcd
fff
ccc
INR 999
MON-SAT 11:00AM-1:00PM

How do I branch inside the post and x variables to get the required info. Thanks

EDIT

I have added spaces in the html. Is it possible to produce a csv of the format without harming the spaces?
DR. XX XXXX,ab cd,f ff,c cc,INR 999,MON-SAT 11:00AM-1:00PM

Answer (score 1):

First off, your indentation looks wrong. Secondly, I don't think you need a `for` loop when just using `find` as it should just return the first match.

if you just want the links, you could try:

```
for link in soup.find("div", {"class": "class1"}).findAll("a"):
  print link.text
```

or, if you want the link itself:

```
for link in soup.find("div", {"class": "class1"}).findAll("a"):
  print link.get("href")
```

You should also note the method used to search for a class, by passing a dict to the `find` method (Edit: I suspect there are other ways of doing this. This is just the way I learnt to do it!)

You can therefore be as specific as you need to be e.g.

```
doctorlink = soup.find(("div", {"class": "class1"}).find("a", {"class": "name"})
```

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> ' '.join(soup.find("div", "class1").getText().split())
u'Dr. XXXXXX abcd fff'
>>> ' '.join(soup.find("div", "class2").getText().split())
u'ccc INR 999 MON-SAT11:00AM-1:00PM 6:00PM-8:00PM'
```

Comment: is there any way to introduce a comma betwwen the different entries that is make it in a csv format