# File Formatting to csv

Tags: python, csv, formatting, newline, pretty-print

I currently have a text file in unicode format which looks something like this

```
Dr. A ABCD
                 abcdef

                 xyzvw

mn o p

qqq qq




Dr. E EFCD

              acdsed

               zxcve
fgh ij

kl mn o
```

I am trying to format it to make it look like this

```
Dr. A ABCD,abcdef,xyzvw,mn o p,qqq qq
Dr. E EFCD,acdsed,zxcve,fgh ij,kl mn o
```

But I always end up eliminating the space between Dr. and A or some other space in between. I have tried to use split() and then ",".join() but I always end up badly formatting the file. Need some help in Python.

EDIT

A space may exist in the entries themselves. I edited the question as such.

Answer (score 0):

Is your file tab delimited?  If so, you should be able to specify that the separator is a tab and Python should be able to detect the hidden line returns (\n).  Here's the documentation: From: http://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html

```
import csv

with open('myfile.csv', 'rb') as myfile:

    myreader = csv.reader(myfile, delimiter='\t')

    for row in myreader:
        print ','.join(row)
```

Edited - Found out that data is from HTML so I recommend using BeautifulSoup4 to keep the data structure.  Documentation is here (http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/)  Added sample code below:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
soup = BeautifulSoup(myfile.html) # Can also be string of text showing HTML

print(soup.prettify())
# <html>
#  <head>
#   <title>...

print soup.title
# Can use this format to get whichever part of the text you're scraping from
```

Comment: Its actually an html file from which I have extracted the texts only. So the remnant spaces are the ones where the tags used to be.

Comment: @Sarkar: Uh... it might be easier to get accurate data if you extract it directly from the original html file; take advantage of the structure instead of throwing it away.

Comment: In that case, I agree with Hugh and think you should keep the format from the HTML.  I recommend using BeautifulSoup4 to do this.  Here's their link: http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/

Comment: I am using the html structure of this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21581147/extracting-scraping-text-from-a-href-inside-p-inside-div/21581468#21581468 but I cant get the spaces right

Answer (score 0):

You can use the regular expression module

```
In [19]: a = """Dr. A ABCD
             abcdef

             xyzvw

mnop

qqqqq



"""

In [20]: ','.join(re.findall('\"[^\"]*\"|\S+', a))
Out[20]: 'Dr.,A,ABCD,abcdef,xyzvw,mnop,qqqqq'
```

Comment: I tried your case but it introduces comma between Dr. and A and ABCD. Is it possible to put it as Dr. A ABCD,abcdef,....

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that all fields contain data, ie there are no blank fields, this will work:

```
from itertools import izip_longest

# from the itertools documentation http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html
def grouper(iterable, n, fillvalue=None):
    "Collect data into fixed-length chunks or blocks"
    # grouper('ABCDEFG', 3, 'x') --> ABC DEF Gxx
    args = [iter(iterable)] * n
    return izip_longest(fillvalue=fillvalue, *args)

txt = (s for s in (line.strip() for line in inf) if s)  # drop all blank lines
doctors = list(grouper(txt, 5, ''))
```

which, on given input, returns

```
[
    ('Dr. A ABCD', 'abcdef', 'xyzvw', 'mnop', 'qqqqq'),
    ('Dr. E EFCD', 'acdsed', 'zxcve', 'fghij', 'klmno')
]
```

Answer (score 0):

I copied your text in a text.txt file.

I just create a new list without the spaces in the beginning of the strings.
Then I print out it as a csv file: separating the values with comma, and adding a newline if 'Dr.' .

Here is my code:

```
with open('text.txt', 'r') as file:
    mytext = file.read()

splitted = mytext.split('\n')


newlist =[] 
for element in splitted:
    i=0
    for i in range(len(element)):
        if element[i] == ' ':
            pass
        else:
            newlist.append(element[i:])  #add to the list
            break

print(newlist)

with open('csv.csv', 'w') as csv:
    for element in newlist:
        if element.startswith('Dr.'):     #start a new line if 'Dr.' 
            csv.write('\n'+ element + ',')
        else:
            csv.write(element + ',')
```

Answer (score -1):

Can't help you in Python specifically but what you need to do is to search and remove the /r/n that you are finding and then trimming the strings that you got as a result.